# SSL Certification Error in deep-translator libary

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-translate

deep_translator version: 1.9.1

Python version: 3.9

Operating System: Win 11

My Code:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator 
translator = GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='pt') 
data = 'my name is python'
translator.translate(data)
```

Error:

ERROR out: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /m?tl=pt&sl=en&q=my+name+is+python(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

Comment: This look like some SSL intercepting "security" system or DNS misconfiguration on your side.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

The issue occurs because of an expired "DST Root CA X3" certificate. The details of certificate remediation are at the link, https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Somehow python SSL libraries are not able to correctly work with this certificate though the browsers are ok.

**Remediation**

Delete the certificate "DST Root CA X3" from all the certificate stores it might exist in. This will resolve the issue.

**Details**

For details of why this issue occurs and access to some tools for further details, look at the README file at this location https://github.com/vivekuppal/transcribe/tree/main/examples/deepgram

This link talks about Deepgram API related issues for SSL Verification failures, though the underlying cause is the same.